# how to zip by exec command line through php

Tags: php, ubuntu, zip, exec

I have a ubuntu server. How can I zip files through executing a command line to zip from my php script

I want to zip the file because the file sizes are too big and zipping it through php will cause more load on server.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need compression I would suggest to look into tar instead of zip as it should be quicker and will result in one file same as zip but without CPU time taken to process the archive

Answer (score 0):

exec, system, fork, - any of the commands can you help execute command line programs with varying levels of control (blocking, non-blocking)

Comment: what should be the command if i want to zip all the files in a particular folder?

Answer (score 0):

$exec = `usr/bin/zip -v zipfile filetozip filetozip2 filetozip3`

The -v is for verbose mode - if you want to check whether the zip worked you can print that out or log it or whatever. Your files will be found in zipfile.zip in the directory from where you ran the command.